# Minimize Outlook windows

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I am currently writing an Outlook add-in using Add-in express.

If I were currently on the 'Mail' tab, is it possible to minimize the 'Inbox' sub-window using .net and C#?

I would like a programmatic way of controlling whether the Inbox window is shown or hidden.

Comment: Crude way is to get the window handle via Process class and then minimze the window.

Comment: @Bali- I dont know if this is something out of the programmer's control or not. If it is, then I was going to ask if this is an API feature for add-in express.

Comment: @zenwalker, what about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289167.aspx ?

Comment: Nope, just commented on Minimizing an application Window using C#

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2007-2010, they introduced the NavigationPane interface; you access it is via the Explorer.NavigationPane property. You need to use NavigationPane.IsCollapsed.